# Why is optional chaining required in an “if let” statement?

Tags: swift

Why would the Swift compiler expect me to write

```
if let addressNumber = paul.residence?.address?.buildingNumber?.toInt() {
}
```

instead of just writing:

```
if let addressNumber = paul.residence.address.buildingNumber.toInt() {
}
```

The compiler clearly has the static type information to handle the conditional statement for the first dereference of the optional value and each following value.

Why would it not continue to do so for the following statements?

Answer (score 4):

Each of those properties is an optional property. It could be valid, or it could be 'not there' (nil). Unlike ObjC, Swift treats nil-references as crashes unless you make them conditional. I would imagine this is for both hygienic and performance reasons, but, regardless, it's a restriction imposed by the language.

Comment: I welcome the explicit `nil` handling. It *is* very convenient to forget about it in Objective-C, but I have been bitten by a silent `nil` many times.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement you posted would be possible if the declaration of the property of each object wasn't optional.

For example:

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var address: Address?
}

class Address {
    var buildingNumber:String?
    var streetName:String?
    var apptNumber:UInt?
}
```

This code would require you to add the conditional markers to make sure that the wrapped property you are trying to access isn't `nil`.

Note that there are no initial values set to those optional types as the `?` infers that the default value is `nil`.

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence
    init(residence: Residence) {
        self.residence = residence
    }
}

class Residence {
    var address: Address
    init(address: Address) {
        self.address = address
    }
}

class Address {
    var buildingNumber:String
    var streetName:String
    var apptNumber:UInt
    init(buildingNumber: String, streetName: String, apptNumber: UInt) {
        self.buildingNumber = buildingNumber
        self.streetName = streetName
        self.apptNumber = apptNumber
    }
}
```

In this second version, the initializer forces you to set a non-nil value to each properties. For an object to be initialized, all its properties need to be initialized as well. Optionals have the convenience of being pre-initialized to nil.

Also, note that all the `?` are gone from the properties declarations for `Person`, `Residence` and `Address`.

If your code was structured that way, your second `if let` statement would work without a problem. But then again, in the second case, there's no need to unwrap your optionals (you don't have any). You could simply call:

```
paul.residence.address.buildingNumber.toInt()
```

And get your value.

I might add that it's way safer to use optionals, as it doesn't force you to use every properties of a class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is that `if let` is a simple way to absolve from checking for nils , and without an optional it's pointless.